# Does my usage of "thereby" have the intended meaning here?

Tags: sentence-construction, modifiers

> Moreover, the socialist states are less prosperous because the means of production are nationalized instead of being under private control, **thereby** reducing incentives for economic progress.

I'm unsure as to whether appending ", thereby..." at the end of my sentence is meaningful or not? I want to mean that as the means of production are being nationalized instead of being under private control, the incentives for economic progress are reduced, but I'm afraid whether I'm meaning that the socialist states being less prosperous is reducing the incentives for economic progress, which makes little sense.

Am I saying what I want to say with the sentence?

Comment: The problem with the sentence is the use of the passive voice (the means of production are nationalised) which doesn't fit with your conclusion **thereby**, meaning **as a result**. I can't see an easy way of rewriting the statement in the active voice (because the socialist states nationalise the means of production). But it does need to be rephrased.

Comment: which thereby reduced incentives etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "thereby" indicates *the result of an action*. In your sentence, however, there is no action. There's only *the state* of the means of production as nationalized, and not under private control.

While the phrase "the means of production are nationalized" is ambiguous and could either describe the process of nationalizing the means of production (an action), or the state of being under national control (a state), it's clear from "instead of being under private control" that the meaning is a state.

There's a couple ways to fix this. One is to make it clear that "the means of production are nationalized" is an action in the passive voice. The other is to use a term other than "thereby".

> ... the means of production are nationalized instead of being **left** under private control, thereby reducing incentives for economic progress.

Here, "nationalized" is understood as the verb, the action of nationalizing, because "left" is also a verb.

> ... the means of production are nationalized instead of being under private control, **which reduces** incentives for economic progress.

In this version, "which" refers to the state of production being under national control rather than private control, and that state reduces incentives for economic progress.